# Try to upload CSV file to MySql using PHP and a HTML form

Tags: php, html

Good day everyone, I am quite new to PHP and I really need some help. I am trying to upload a CSV file to MySql database using PHP and HTML `<form>`, but it is giving me the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: `temp_name` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\import csv\importcsv.php` on line 23
>
> Warning: `fopen()`: Filename cannot be empty in `C:\xampp\htdocs\import csv\importcsv.php` on line 24
>
> Warning: `fgetcsv()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in `C:\xampp\htdocs\import csv\importcsv.php` on line 26
>
> Warning: `fclose()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in `C:\xampp\htdocs\import csv\importcsv.php` on line 30
>   successfully imported

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pwd = '';

    $db = 'mydb';
    $table = 'user';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die("Cant connect to database");

    if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,$db))
        die("Cant select to database");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
        echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';
        $chk_ext = explode(".",  $fname);

        if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv"){ 
            $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['temp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

            while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) != FALSE){
                $sql = "INSERT into user(name,email,phone) values('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]')";
                mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            }
            fclose($handle);
            echo "successfully imported";
        } else{
            echo "Invalid file";
        }
    }

?>
<h1>Import csv file</h1>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Please help.

Comment: What kind of form are you using ? Do you have this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form tag ?

Comment: Well, we need the code to see why you get these errors. Of course.

Comment: This is incorrect - $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['temp_name']; It should be $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];  It is tmp_name and not temp_name